# Extruding inwards along edges?

Tags: modeling

I have this shape that I want to extrude into. Here's a picture of the situation:

[image]

I want to extrude so that it fills in evenly so I can pull it out, add a mirror mod and have the blade looking all nice, however i cant seem to figure out how to extrude along edge normals. How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for the **inset** tool. create a face from your edge boundary by selecting all vertices (like in your screenshot) and hit  <kbd>f</kbd>. Then hit <kbd>i</kbd> and drag with the mouse to create the faces.

[image]

Or, if you want to extrude to the normal of the face, use  <kbd>f</kbd>, then  <kbd>e</kbd> instead.

Comment: This worked! Required some cleanup, but was what I needed :)

Answer (score 9):

Instead of creating your object as a mesh, create a curve to trace the outline of your object:

[image]

When you are done tracing make sure you close the curve. Select the first and last segments and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

On the properties window set the curve to **2D**, Fill to **Both** and use the **Bevel** settings

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hrm I never thought of this method! I will definitely have to try it out!

Comment: I cant seem to get mine to fill in more than just the bevel :o How did you make yours do that?

Comment: @elemein Did you **close** the curve? (select the first and last segment of the curve and press Alt+C) Did you set the shape as **2D** and the fill as **Both**?

Comment: Ah! I didnt close my curve. There was my issue :)

Answer (score 1):

After you <kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>middle mouse button</kbd> and drag your mouse in the direction of the axis.

this will snap your extrusion to one of the three axis x/y/z